# Using tensorflow.js to predict movie desirability based on genre

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

using the default basic example of [tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) website I'm trying to change it so by giving it an array that specifies movie genres it can predict if I will like the movie or not:

```js
  // Define a model for linear regression.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

  // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
  // Generate some synthetic data for training.

  //[action, adventure, romance]
  const xs = tf.tensor1d([1,1,0]);
  //target data should be rating from 1 to 5
  const ys = tf.tensor1d([3]);

  // Train the model using the data.
  model.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
    // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
    // Open the browser devtools to see the output
    model.predict(tf.tensor2d([1,0,0])).print();
  });
```

however, regarding the `const ys = tf.tensor1d([3]);` it throws an error telling me that `Input Tensors should have the same number of samples as target Tensors. Found 3 input sample(s) and 1 target sample(s)`, but I want a prediction from an array[3] to a number from 1 to 5 and I don't know how to achieve this using this sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of samples should match the number of targets, otherwise model can not learn. I updated your example, added another sample, and another target, and corrected the shapes.

```
// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputDim: 3 }));

// Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' });
// Generate some synthetic data for training.

//[action, adventure, romance]
const xs = tf.tensor2d([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]);
//target data should be rating from 1 to 5
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[3], [2]]);

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
  // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
  // Open the browser devtools to see the output
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[1, 0, 0]])).print();
});
```

this compiles and produces the following result:

```
Tensor
     [[1.6977279],]
```

Comment: The way I see it you only changed `inputDim` parameter of the dense layer, is that correct?

Comment: @mohas also changed the shape of input `[[1,0,1,]]` and output `[[3]]`, and made them `tensor2d`